# Массив кнопок с изображениями

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Необходимо создать массив кнопок с изображением, на каждую кнопку свое, но картинка лепится только на последнюю кнопку. Пошерстил гугл, понял, что надо каким-то образом передать параметр 'image' в явном виде, но не могу понять как это сделать.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

PATH = os.getcwd()

work_dir = os.listdir(PATH + '\\' + 'images')
num_of_pics = len(work_dir)
field = Tk()

row = 0
column = 0

for i in range(num_of_pics):
    img_name = (PATH + '\\' + 'images\\' + str(i) + ".png")
    img_op = Image.open(img_name)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_op)
    but = Button(width=15,
                 height=15,
                 image=img)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        row += 1
        column = 0
    but.grid(row=row, column=column)
    column += 1
field.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае все изображения кроме последнего удаляются сборщиком мусора (см. например "Note" в конце этой статьи: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)). С точки зрения сборщика мусора перезапись старого значения переменной `img` означает, что на предыдущее значение (изображение) больше нет ссылок, значит можно спокойно удалить его из памяти. Чтобы удаление не произошло, можно сохранить ссылки на изображения в список, тогда изображения не будут удалены сборщиком мусора, пока существует список:

```
images = []

for i in range(num_of_pics):
    ...
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_op)
    images.append(img)  # <<< сохраняем изображение в список
    but = Button(width=15,
                 height=15,
                 image=img)
    ...
```

Без сохранения изображения в списке:

[image: no list]

С сохранением:

[image: magic]